# What do you call a person who verifies the receipt and the shopping items at the exit of a store?

Tags: single-word-requests, expressions

how to express it in a short sentence and in a casual way to tell your friend that there is a big waiting line at the exit door of a store as the staff was verifying the receipt and shopping items

Comment: Usually those are store security guards.

Comment: *There is a big waiting line at the exit door in front of the* **checker**.

Comment: They're not common here, but when you do see them they're *usually* wearing a security uniform rather than a shop assistant uniform, and may well have a badge or other identifier reading "security".  I have occasionally seen an attendant who looks after multiple self-checkout machines carrying out a similar role.  Even in that case "security guard" would get the message across better than anything else -- "It's going to take ages getting out. The security guard is checking everyone's receipts"

Comment: They don't use security guards to check receipts at Costco or Walmart. They are regular-looking employees. As to their official job titles are, I couldn't tell you. "Checker" sounds good as anything else I suppose. The person checking the receipt at Walmart (if any) is usually the greeter as well. My guess checking receipts is simply another task assigned to certain employees hired to do other things rather than checking receipts as a full time position.

Comment: "The creep at the door who checks your receipt."

Comment: Ironically, they are called "greeters". Their function is to get you to stand still long enough for the facial recognition software to ID you.  http://work.chron.com/job-description-people-greeter-19106.html

Comment: @mahmudkoya - However, "checker" is a common term for a person operating a cash register.

Comment: Once you have purchased the items at a register, they are yours, and you do not have to show either these items or the receipt to anyone, whether greeter or security person or police officer; and even the latter would have to have  *probable cause* that you have committed a crime between the register and the exit, before they can search you. You can, legally, decline any receipt or item check. (This is in the USA,  and this comment  does not consist of legal advice.)

Comment: @Clare You have evidently never been to Costco, where *all* receipts are reviewed at the exit and such inspection is explicitly required in the [membership terms and conditions](https://www.costco.com/member-privileges-conditions.html).

Comment: It's true that I'm not a member of a store whose rules  require me to give up my legal rights.  @choster

Comment: we  call them 'security' and speak to them as mr or ms

Answer (score 1):

They are called **loss prevention associates/specialists** and the job description for that position can be found online under that term:

Here is an example of one description ([from snagajob.com](http://www.snagajob.com/job-descriptions/loss-prevention/)):

> Most loss prevention specialists work at the front of the store, examining purchase receipts and greeting customers. Their primary goal is verifying that each customer is leaving the store with only the merchandise they've purchased. You will need to be highly attentive to detail and very friendly.

The descriptions typically go on to say that their may be other loss prevention tasks for this person to do, depending on experience and need. The position is not the same as that of a security guard.

Answer (score 0):

There is mandatory (spelled out in the membership agreement) checking at the door of wholesale clubs such as Sam's Club and Costco. Most people call them 'receipt checkers'. You can find many references in news reports and blogs using that term. For example:

> [What do the Costco receipt checkers actually look for in your cart when you leave the store?](https://www.quora.com/What-do-the-Costco-receipt-checkers-actually-look-for-in-your-cart-when-you-leave-the-store)

and

> [Costco shopper who broke leg after shoving receipt checker loses lawsuit seeking $610,000](http://www.oregonlive.com/portland/index.ssf/2015/11/costco_shopper_who_broke_leg_a.html)

I was not able to find their formal title- probably they don't want applicants specifically seeking that kind of security-related position.

In non-membership stores it is not all that commonly done, in my experience, though if you make a purchase inside at a special desk (for example for goods that may require a special license) you may be asked to keep your receipt out to show it to the cashiers on the way out. Stores with a bad theft problem may be more aggressive.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for a word to replace [Validator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/validate#source-word-origin), in one of my projects, I found [Validator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/validate#source-word-origin) in the [related forms](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/validate#source-word-origin) section for [validate](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/validate), I also came across [Approver](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/approver).

in your case I might just chose a prefix, like purchase or receipt, and append [Validator](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/validate#source-word-origin) or [Approver](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/approver).

> Hand the receipt to the *Purchase Validator*.

alternatively

> We must meet with the *Receipt Approver* before leaving.

Answer (score 0):

> There is a big waiting line at the exit as [security](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/security) is checking
>   receipts.

measures adopted, as by a business or homeowner, to prevent a crime such as burglary